# Is there a pattern to be followed to add classes inline in the AWS lambda_function.py?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a correctly working python script on my local machine which I would like to implement on AWS Lambda now.

It has the following general structure:

```
#import statements
#CONSTANTS
#non-class functions
#class def
##class func1
##class func2
#if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I read on a [git repo](https://gist.github.com/benkehoe/efb75a793f11d071b36fed155f017c8f) that we should have a pattern when we are trying to insert a python script into AWS Lambda. Do we have to put the class in a separate file? I'm not sure if I understand the pattern on that repo correctly. So far I've been just running it in a single script, the way I do on my local machine.

Comment: If you have everything in a single file, just use it as it is. Keep in mind you need a function you'll use as Lambda handler function to be the entry point for AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pattern to follow when adding classes to an AWS Lambda. It is perfectly fine to have all of the classes, constants, and other methods within one file.

However, it would be wise to separate this information into separate files. This allows for easier development and more flexibility when implementing features. The link you provided is just one example of many options you could do to achieve code flexibility.

If you're a new developer, I'd recommend keeping all the content in one file. As you become more comfortable with developing and or see how some parts of your code can be re-used, then split up your code into multiple files.

It should also be stated that Lambdas are designed to be small and quick pieces of code. So don't go overboard on separating files. If your lambda is too large, consider splitting it up into multiple lambdas.